# how to send query

Tags: javascript, asp.net

How to send query from javascript to asp.net, and then asp.net return it javascript?

```
var=select * from read//send to asp.net
asp.net return values to javascript
```

Thank you

Comment: Why would you want to send a query using javascript?

Answer (score 5):

Don't.

You cannot send raw SQL queries from client side JavaScript to your server without opening yourself up to severe security problems.

Design an API instead.

1. Decide what types of queries you need to make
2. Decide what user input you need
3. Write ASP.NET programs that accept either POST or GET requests (depending on if the request is [safe](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.1) or not)
4. Make the queries from ASP.NET, making sure to [avoid SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com/csharp.html)
5. Have the ASP.NET programs return the data in a structured format (such as [JSON](http://json.org) or XML)
6. Use XMLHttpRequest or JSON-P (probably via a library such as [YUI](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/io/) or [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to make the HTTP requests from JavaScript including just the parameters you need to insert into the queries

Comment: An end to end example would be a significant piece of work, so no.